# Creating multiple unrelated associated model instances in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have what I believe is fairly simple model setup:

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :booking
end
```

Now, I want to create a form that allows a user to register payments in batch. That is, the form should have a number of input rows, each one representing a payment for *some* booking (i.e., each row has some fields for the columns of `Payment` plus a `booking_id` field). Upon submitting, each row should cause the creation of a corresponding `Payment`, which should be associated with the `Booking` indicated by the user for that row.

This seems to be surprisingly tricky, and my Google-Fu is failing me. I've tried the following (inspired by [this](https://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/) post describing a solution without associations), which I thought would work, but which, well, doesn't:

```rb
class Admin::PaymentController < Admin::Controller
  def batch
    @payments = []
    5.times do
      @payments << Payment.new
    end
  end

  def submit
    params["payments"].each do |payment|
      if payment["booking_id"] != "" || payment["amount"] != ""
        Payment.create(payment_params(payment))
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def payment_params(p)
    p.permit(:booking_id, :amount)
  end
end
```

```rb
<%= form_tag admin_payment_submit_path do %>
  <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
    <%= fields_for 'payments[]', payment do |p| %>
      <%=p.text_field :booking_id%>
      <%=p.number_field :amount%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

This renders the form without erroring out, but the HTML names work out such that only a single payment (the last one) is submitted (e.g., `name="payments[booking_id]"`). Furthermore, upon submitting, I get the error

```
undefined method `permit' for "booking_id":String Did you mean? print
```

Which is less than helpful.

I've tried other variations too, but I feel like at this point I'm just feeling my way in the dark. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` in controller is a instance of `ActiveController::Parameter` that has `permit` method.
But `params["payments"]` is a just array as subset of params.

For multiple payment params

```
def submit
  payment_params.each do |payment|
    if payment["booking_id"].present? || payment["amount"].present?
      Payment.create(payment)
    end
  end
end

private

def payment_params
  params.permit(payments: [:booking_id, :amount])["payments"]
end
```

For Single payment param

```
def submit
  if payment_param["booking_id"].present? || payment_param["amount"].present?
    Payment.create(payment_param)
  end
end

private
def payment_param
  params.require(:payments).permit(:a, :b)
end
```

Comment: Hmm, that gives me the error "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument." on `Payment.create(payment)`

Comment: Probably related, the Rails server shows `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "payments"=>{"booking_id"=>"", "amount"=>"", "paid_at"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save changes"}`. Note how there is only one payment, and how it is empty (I filled out the first, not the last).

Comment: `payment_parmas` is a array of hash and `payment` is a hash. isn't it?

Comment: It's whatever the form code posted in the question produces. After some further prodding, it looks like I need to use `payments[][]`. At least now I'm getting an error about a foreign key constraint for `booking_id` is violated (which makes sense given that I used a bogus value).

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. With `payments[][]` substituted for `payments[]` in the form code in my question, plus your changes, things seem to work correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Given that the question was specifically about multiple payments, it's probably clearer if you keep the answer only about that, and maybe also mention the `[]` change too.